# Batch for PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, plsql, command-line

1) The `pgpass.conf` (of PostgreSQL) is:

```sh
localhost:5432:*:postgres:mypassword
```

I have no experience with batch and I have spent the day searching in the net.
I'm using Windows - if that matters.

2) I tried with a file.bat as:

```sh
cd C:
start "" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" "C:\Users\utente\Desktop\1Giswater impNode.sql"
pause
start "" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" "C:\Users\utente\Desktop\2Giswater impArc.sql"
pause
start "" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" "C:\Users\utente\Desktop\3assegnazione enet.sql"
pause
```

After typing my password the result is:

[image: psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied]

3) I've written a simple `file.bat`, which is:

```sh
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\
pause
rem psql --help
pause
psql   -e -a -f="C:\Users\utente\Desktop\1Giswater impNode.sql"   -d=postgres  -U=postgres
```

The result is:

[image: psql: opzione di connessione errata]

What am I missing?

Comment: Where exactly is `pgpass.conf` located? Does it work if you start `psql` manually?

Comment: the path is: C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\pgpass.conf

Comment: Manually I launch the psql.exe then insert the passwaord but it says: `psql: FATALE: autenticazione con password fallita per l'utente "utente" ` where "utente" is the pc user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the username incorrectly:

The "short" parameter names don't use the `=` sign:

So it should either be:

```sh
psql -e -a -f"C:\Users\utente\Desktop\1Giswater impNode.sql" -dpostgres  -Upostgres
```

or, when using the long parameter names:

```sh
psql -e -a --file="C:\Users\utente\Desktop\1Giswater impNode.sql" --dbname=postgres  --username=postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@echo off

set PGUSER=Postgres UserName
set PGPASSWORD=Postgres Password
set PGDATABASE=DB Name
set postgresPort=5432
set PSQL="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe"

echo SELECT * FROM -(YourDATA)- WHERE '-(YourDATA)-'; | %PSQL% -h localhost -U %PGUSER% -d %PGDATABASE%

pause
```